# Contact Form fields not being passed

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, post

I am working on a simple contact form however when the email comes through the fields are empty. The form sends fine but it doesn't get any of the values. My form HTML looks like this.

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
  <input type="text" name="namefirst" id="namefirst" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name">
  <input type="text" name="namefirst" id="namefirst" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your email address">
  <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="input-block-level" rows="8"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right">Send Message</button>
```

The PHP side of things is as follows

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
   $status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);

$nameFirst = $_POST['namefirst'];
$nameLast = $_POST['namelast']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$subject = $message;

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'jdwman14@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $nameFirst .' '. $nameLast. "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);

die;
```

When the email comes through it has this format but has none of the variables.

Name:

Email:

Subject:

Message:

Comment: put a `print_r($_POST)` and see what you get into the array.

Comment: Apart from that: you have two times the same name (``namefirst``) - Be sure to check that ``count($_POST) > 0`` and that the values are set (Hint: ``isset()``).

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in Form, 
There are two time namefirst input field in your form

```
  <input type="text" name="namefirst" id="namefirst" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name">
```

replace namefirst with lastname in name & id attribute value in second input as following,

```
<input type="text" name="namelast" id="namelast" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your Last Name">
```

I hope this solve your issue...

Comment: I make a guess: it will not :-). The other form values are also not set.

Comment: @thedom, as form html, you can see `required="required"` attribute in fields, @j0siah has already set validation using jquery, so i thing all form fields will not blank at time of submit.

Comment: That's completety irrelevant in case of php. If these attribute is set or not doesn't change a thing apart from the fact that modern browsers will notify you to enter the value before submitting the form. Older browsers don't care about that.